# How VB6 host .net 2.0

Tags: c#, vb.net, interop, clr, com-interop

We want to call some .net Assemblies from VB6.
I know we can register the .net Assemblies to COM by Regasm command and then call it from VB6.
But now we want to host the CLR 2.0 in VB6.

I know we can call CorRuntimeHost class to host the CLR. But MSDN said it is obselete. After googled some days, I found many people use CorBindToRuntimeEx to host CLR. but all these samples are based on C/C++. Sorry I did not find any sampels using VB6.

So does anyone know how to use VB6 to host .net framework 2.0. Except the CorRuntimeHost class, is there any another way to host .net framework in VB6?

Comment: I hope you know that this sounds like a crazy plan. VB6 supports COM, and .NET supports COM, so why not stick to COM? Also, will you even want to use a later version of .NET?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I know it is crazy. Our main purpose is to support Xcopy. I know com support multiple versions, but you know there is something called Dll hell which is really painful so we are trying to find out all possible solution. Since our VB application will still exists for some years, so we are tring to find out workaround.

Comment: You know, if you're really trying to modernize, you should create the .NET code as WCF services that the VB6 code can consume through COM wrappers. You can then evolve each of the services independently, and don't need the maintenance headache of hosting .NET inside of VB6. I mean, just think of the number of times you'll have to _explain_ that to people over the years. It's much easier to say, "legacy VB6 app consuming SOA services through COM wrappers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub LoadLib()
 Dim unknown As IUnknown
 Dim domain As AppDomain
 Dim handle As ObjectHandle
 Dim path As String

 On Local Error GoTo OOPS

 path = GetDLLPath()

 Set m_host = New CorRuntimeHost
 With m_host
    .Start
    .GetDefaultDomain unknown
 End With

 Set domain = unknown
 Set handle = domain.CreateInstanceFrom(path, "STHRest.CXlService")
 Set m_lib = handle.Unwrap

OOPS:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    m_err = Err.Description
    Call RemoveCLR
End If

On Local Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
```

End Sub

Comment: Private Sub LoadLib()
 Dim unknown As IUnknown
 Dim domain As AppDomain
 Dim handle As ObjectHandle
 Dim path As String
 
    On Local Error GoTo OOPS
       
    path = GetDLLPath()
    
    Set m_host = New CorRuntimeHost
    With m_host
        .Start
        .GetDefaultDomain unknown
    End With
    
    Set domain = unknown
    Set handle = domain.CreateInstanceFrom(path, "STHRest.CXlService")
    Set m_lib = handle.Unwrap
     
OOPS:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        m_err = Err.Description
        Call RemoveCLR
    End If
    
    On Local Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Comment: Could you explain why this code can help to answer OP's question?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer finally. I posted it here since maybe it is usefule for someone else.

You can refere mscorlib.tlb in excel VBA, then:

```
Dim ap as ApplicationDomain, apm As mscorlib.AppDomainManager, result as object
Set apm = New mscorlib.AppDomainManager
Set m_domain = apm.CreateDomain("kissingerDomain", Nothing, Nothing)
set object = m_domain.CreateInstanceFrom(DLL_Path, typeName).Unwrap
```

Now you can call the object method , haha.

Comment: This code does not work: `m_domain` does not get initialized (Object required error), and `Dim ap As ApplicationDomain` throws a `User-defined type not defined` error. Did you really make it work?

Comment: yes, it does works. Did you add reference of mscorlib.tlb?

Answer (score 0):

The CLR host must be a unmanaged, native, application. It is not possible to host the CLR *directly* using VB6.

The only way to make it possible is to write a C++ DLL which exposes __declspec C functions, and use those functions from your VB6 application. [Someone did it for FoxPro, so there is some hope](http://west-wind.com/wconnect/weblog/ShowEntry.blog?id=631).

Even assuming that it plays well (I have no idea if the COM layers in the two "pieces" (the VB6 VM and the host) will play nicely together) you still have to do it in C++. 
So.. listen to John Saunders comment. Don't do that, choose another path.